# C++ Win32 Project: Error "Unable to start program. Cannot find the file specified"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Tengo un probelma con visual studio 2010. Al crear un nuevo projecto utilizando Win32 Project y al hacerlo correr sin hacer ningún cambio sale este error:

```
Unable to start program 'c:\users\....\xx.exe'. 
Cannot find the file specified"
```

¿Podría alguien decirme cómo puedo solucionar esto?

Comment: Por cierto, ya que has vuelto, considera revisar tus preguntas anteriores porque algunas recibieron respuesta y, si alguna de las mismas soluciona el problema, considera marcarla como solución. Así ayudarás a futuros usuarios del portal

Answer (score 0):

Estás intentando ejecutar el programa antes de haberlo compilado. Prueba a compilar el programa y después intenta ejecutarlo. Debería funcionar.

Otra posibilidad es que el proyecto sea compuesto y no esté seleccionado el proyecto ejecutable como proyecto de inicio. Edita la configuración de la solución para que el proyecto de inicio sea el proyecto ejecutable.

Una última que se me ocurre estaría relacionada con los permisos de acceso, pero esto ya es demasiado presuponer sin tener ni idea acerca de la configuración de tu sistema operativo.